# SVG fill animation using javascript

Tags: html, animation, svg, raphael, fill

I have an svg image. And I want to create a 'fill animation' on this image so that the image will start filling with a color from one end of the image and then go on to completely fill the image with some color. 
Say, in an image the color will start filling from the extreme right and slowly go on filling as if it is drawing the actual image.
Can this be done in javascript.

Comment: You can achieve this by filling the shape with a linear gradient and then animating the stops

Comment: I have an svg image. I used raphael-svg-import-classic plugin to import an svg image. Now I need to perform a fill animation on the Element.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to probably use jQuery mixed with the 3rd party library named Velocity.

Velocity is a library that deals specifically for color, transforms, loops, easings, SVG and scrolling animations.

```js
$("#rect")
  .delay(1000)
  .velocity({
    fill: "#ff0000",
    height: "100",
    width: "100"
  }, {
    duration: 1000
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.2/velocity.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect id="rect" width="25" height="25" x="10%" y="10%" fill="gray" stroke="rgba(80, 80, 80, 1)" stroke-width="0px" />
</svg>
```

Obviously this demo is very simple but there are a lot of customization's available and without any prior code in your question it will be hard to get the exact effect you are looking for.

- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
- [Velocity](http://julian.com/research/velocity/)